# Stop Survey Alerts

Tags: office-365, survey, survey-list

Surveys can be anonymous.  But if someone creates an alert to that survey, the email sent by the alert has their image on it! .. no name.

I have tried creating a NoAlerts permission level, but this does not seem to work on surveys.

Is there a way to fix this? .. or another way to for users to give anonymous suggestions?